# Docusign password reset - Rest api

Tags: docusignapi

In Docusign documentation for password change (Api - https:/restapi/v2/login_information/password with attribute values of currentPassword,email,forgottenPasswordAnswer1,forgottenPasswordQuestion1,newPassword) , is there any other direct approach in order to update the password?

Answer (score 1):

Only `/restapi/v2/login_information/password` endpoint is available for Password change. Even on WEBApp, DS asks the same info and makes the same API call.[image: WebApp_Chng_Pwd]